# xslt in xml attribute

Tags: xslt, attributes

I have xml element tyle boleean.

```
<testelement>0</testelement>
```

I use xslt to transform value to no/yes depending on 0/1 value and it works great

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./text()='0'">
        <xsl:text>No</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="./text()='1'">
        <xsl:text>Yes</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">The Yes/No value to be translated did not match expected input</xsl:message>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

The same I try to do with attribute type boolean. Element has maxOcc unbounded.

```
<element attribute="0">
...
</element>
<element attribute="1">
...
</element>
```

In xlts:

```
<xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="//@attribute='0'">
        <xsl:text>No</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
                   <xsl:when test="//@attribute='1'">
        <xsl:text>Yes</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:message terminate="no">The Yes/No value to be translated did not match expected input</xsl:message>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But after i use this code all values are Yes or all values are No depending what is value in first node element. EG if 0 is in first element all values are No and it doesnd matter that in second is 1. 
How to transform it properly?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you think you need to `xsl:choose` at all, simple template matching `testelement[. = 0]`, `testelement[. = 1]` and `testelement` would do. The same way you can write templates matching e.g. `element/@attribute[. = 0]`, `element/@attribute[. = 1]`. As for your attempt, in the context of an element the path `@attribute` selects its attribute named `attribute`, your attempt with `//@attribute` selects `/descendant-or-self::node()/@attribute`, that is, all attributes named `attribute` in the context document/tree.

Comment: Thank You, may I ask You for example how to use template matching in my case? Without any transformation my code looks like this:  <td style="padding-left:10px; width:1.64in; "><xsl:for-each select="@attribute"><span style="color:#0024c0; "><xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/></span></xsl:for-each></td>

Comment: It is not clear how the code you have put into the comment relates to the rest you have presented in your question. Also you have not presented any context for the XSLT snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> all values are Yes or all values are No
>   depending what is value in first node element

Yes, of course they are. That's because your test:

```
<xsl:when test="//@attribute='0'">
```

selects **all** the attributes in the XML document, and in XSLT 1.0 (which I assume you're using) only the first one's value will be used.

---

You need first to be in the context of `element`, then test that specific element's attribute by:

```
<xsl:when test="@attribute='0'">
```

Comment: Thanks, ok now I understand but I dont know how to be in the context of 'element' hmmm

Comment: I don't know that either because I can't see the context. Both your XML and XSLT are fragments. Please see: [mcve]. -- In general, you establish the context either in the `xsl:template`'s `match` attribute or by `xsl:for-each`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way to do it:

```
<xsl:template match="node()[.='0'] | @*[.='0']" mode="toYesNo"/>No</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()[.='1'] | @*[.='1']" mode="toYesNo"/>Yes</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="toYesNo"/>
  <xsl:message terminate="no">The Yes/No value to be translated did not match expected input</xsl:message>
</xsl:template>
```

and then you can `xsl:apply-templates` (with `mode="toYesNo"`) selecting any element, attribute, or text node to get the appropriate conversion.

In XSLT 3.0 you can replace the patterns withm for example, `match=".[.='0']"` to match any kind of node.

Try to avoid using `./text()` because it goes wrong when there are comments in your XML. You can nearly always replace it with `.`.

And of course you error with the attributes was the leading `//`. You need to be very clear about the difference between absolute path expressions (which start with `/` and select from the root of the tree) and relative path expressions (which select from the node you are current processing).